# can't affix footer when using mmenu

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mmenu

I have a problem. When coding the side pages of the site, I can not tie the footer to the basement of the site. I use bootsrap classes. When trying to use such code:

```
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}
body {
  /* Margin bottom by footer height */
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}
#footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

the footer either remains in place, or it closes the content, approaching the navigation bar.
How can this problem be solved?

before
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qeg7Q.png

after use the code
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XnnaS.png

P.S. I apologize for bad english

Answer (score 0):

Height of `100%` doesn't work like you think it would. In this case, you're looking for `vh` units. I would also apply them to `body`, not `html`.

```css
*{box-sizing: border-box;}

body {
  /* Margin bottom by footer height */
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}
footer {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
  content
  <footer>
    footer
  </footer>
</body>
```

Comment: I tried. But everything remains the same.
I have such a site structure:
<body>
<div id="my-page">
<div id="my-header"></div>
<div id="my-content"></div>
<div id="my-footer"></div>
</div>
</body>